# React app not working in Safari. Working fine on Chrome and FireFox but giving black layout for safari

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docker, safari, cross-browser

My react app works in every browser, But not working in Safari on MacOS(Catalina OS & Version 13.1.2 ). I get no error, no console message, nothing that would give me some idea. It only renders blank screen in Safari.

Some people suggest me to clear the cache or turn off the cache and then reload the page but that doesn’t work for me.

I tried to run my react app locally in safari and then I was getting these error messages in the console :-

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: A server with the specified hostname could not be found.
```

```
[Error] The source list for Content Security Policy directive 'script-src' contains an invalid source: ''strict-dynamic''. It will be ignored.
```

Do you have any idea how could I fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the development or production version? `npm run start` or `npm run build`?

Comment: I'm using a development version. (npm run start)

Comment: Ok, I've experienced an issue like this before and it was because I was running it in development mode. On safari there are some issues where if you don't use the correct polyfills, it will display a blank screen. Try building and then running serve to see if it runs correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. The main reason why it failed was 'callback' function that was not triggered in safari. So I checked on official website of google(https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) about google sign-in and I got that we should use (meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com")  and it fixed the issue. Now it's working fine in every browser.